# Using Axios instance in Vue 3

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a Vue plugin for creating an axios instance which I want to use for all my api calls.

**plugins/axios.ts**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import type { App } from 'vue'

interface AxiosOptions {
    baseUrl: string
}

function isIsoDateString(value: any): boolean {
    ...
}

function handleDates(body: any) {
   ...
}

export default {
    install: (app: App, options: AxiosOptions) => {

        const axiosInstance = axios.create({
            baseURL: options.baseUrl,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        });
        
        axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(originalResponse => {
            handleDates(originalResponse.data);
            return originalResponse;
        });

        app.provide("axios", axiosInstance);
    }
}
```

This plugin is then added to the app in the createApp call:

**main.ts**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import mitt from "mitt";

import axios from "@/plugins/axios";
import App from "./App.vue"
import router from "./router";

const emitter = mitt();

const app = createApp(App)
    .use(router)
    .use(createPinia())
    .use(axios, {baseUrl: "http://localhost:15454/"});

app.provide("emitter", emitter);
app.mount("#app");
```

Within my api calls I simply use it like this:

**actions/providers.ts**

```
import { inject } from 'vue'
import type { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { type Provider } from "../types/Provider";


export const getProviders = async (activeOnly: boolean): Promise<Provider[]> => {

    const ax = inject('axios') as AxiosInstance;

    try {

        const response = await ax.get(`/Provider/${activeOnly}`);
        return response.data;

    } catch (error) {
        ...
        return [];
    }
};
```

This approach works when calls to the api are made during setup.
However, I am getting the error

> inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.

when the api call is initiated from an event handler eg.

```
    <script setup lang="ts">
        const handleClick = async () => {
            const value = await getProviders(true);
        }
    </script>
    <template>
        <button @click="handleClick">Submit</button>
    </template>
```

Why does this happen with an event handler? What do I need to do to use axios in this way?

Comment: Why not just export the Axios instance as a regular module? There doesn't appear to be any reason to use a plugin for this

Comment: @Phil - It was originally a module, however, the axios baseUrl needs to change depending on env i.e. dev/test/prod. In the example above the baseUrl is hardcoded but in reality this comes from a config file which is read using another plugin following the provide/inject pattern. The problem with the module approach was that it was being loaded before the config values had been provided via creatApp so I was having to read the config twice (once for createApp and again within the axios module).

Comment: I see. I'd just use environment variables to control different env properties, eg `import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL`